# Wordpress Logout 404

Tags: php, wordpress, logout

Logout link not logging out and going to weird url.

```
<?php
 if (is_user_logged_in()) {
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  echo 'Hi <strong><a href="http://zanifesto.com/membership-account" rel="nofollow">'.$user->display_name.'</a></strong> | <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>';
} else { ?>
  Please <strong><?php wp_loginout(); ?></strong>
  or <a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/wp-login.php?action=register"> <strong>Register</strong></a>

<?php }?>
```

Url it takes you to is: http://zanifesto.com/%3C?php%20echo%20wp_logout_url(%20home_url()%20);%20?%3E

How do I

1. Make the logout link actually log you out; and
2. Make it redirect to the homepage instead of homepage/php code?

I have already tried deactivating all the plugins to see if there was a conflict. I have not altered the wp-login file and I don't have any custom theme functions regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shoudl work: double and single qoutes were getting messed up.

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()) :
$user = wp_get_current_user();?>

Hi<strong>
    <a href='http://zanifesto.com/membership-account' rel='nofollow'>
        <?php echo $user->display_name ?>
    </a>
</strong> |<a href='<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>' title='Logout'>Logout</a>
<?php else:?>

Please <strong><?php wp_loginout(); ?></strong>
or<a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/wp-login.php?action=register">
    <strong>Register</strong>
</a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
  <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>"  title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

to

```
  <a href="'. wp_logout_url( home_url() ) .'"  title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

Try it and let me know please